# Using $observe for variable creation

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to come up with code that would monitor scope variable creation. Here is my code in directive:

```
attrs.$observe('disable', function () {
                if (scope.abc === true)
                    ....;
            });
```

The element has an attribute 'disable' set to a scope's variable abc:

```
disable="scope.abc"
```

My problem is that the scope.abc initially doesn't exist. So when code in the directive runs scope.abc cannot be evaluated. But when it's created the observe is not called. Is there a solution for something like this?

Thanks

Comment: You likely have XY problem that results in having troubles with design. Don't use $observe, unless you really know that it should be used here. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: $observe detects when the attribute changes, but in your case the attribute value is not changing. Maybe you can further describe your scenario so someone can suggest an alternative.